# "Be as adjective"

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, as

> My girls are on the wait list for their  preschool and it is ***twice
>   as tough*** to get in with twins.

Marked phrase kind of puzzled me. I quoted this from a tv-series.

We don't know the second part of the "as adjective as ..." form here. Getting with twins is twice as tough compared to what? I think this is a reduced use of this form.

Mıght this be the full form ?

> It is twice ***as*** tough to get in with twins ***as*** to get in with one kid.

Comment: It looks like a mistake or typo to me. I suspect it should be *twice as **long** to get in with twins*.

Comment: I didn't mean that you had transcribed it incorrectly, just that it could be a mistake or typo in the source material or by the author. My take was that *the wait list is twice as long*. Although, thinking about it again, perhaps ***though*** was meant to be ***tough***. That's just an *h* away.

Comment: You heard it wrong, unfortunately. It's obviously *tough*, and I looked it up, and the guy says *tough*. I'm sorry. Everyone makes mistakes. I suggest you either get better subtitles or just turn them off completely. I know it may be hard, but if you're trying to learn English, it might be the only way (if you're not sure what they said after listening to it, pause the show and consult the (better) subtitles).

Comment: Further, if you listen to the pronunciations of *tough* and *though* at https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/though, you can hear (and see, if you're familiar with the [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects)) that the word *tough* begins with a /t/ instead of a /ð/, and has an /ʌ/ in the middle as opposed to an /oʊ/.

Comment: Ah  yes. So sorry. I wrote it down incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your guess is right.

> It is twice as tough to get in with twins as to get in with one kid.

Comment: Are this kind of reductions common in everyday speech?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden - Yes.

Comment: I suppose this kind of reduction is appropriate when the other part of the comparison is guessable?

Comment: Very good.  Please feel free to make up another example and post it here.